# Entity Framework 4: Image type?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am creating an Entity Data Model for a document. I want to store the body of the document as a BLOB--document bodies will be larger than the varbinary max. As I understand things, what I need to do is create a property of type `Image` to store the document body.

Here's my problem: The types listed in the Properties pane do not include an `Image` type:

[image]

Does EF4 recognize an `Image` type? If so, how do I create an entity property of type `Image`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Image` is deprecated, you should use `varbinary(MAX)` instead - but if you are using files larger than 2GB (as you apparently are since `varbinary(MAX)` would otherwise be sufficient) you probably should bypass this altogether and save them on disk - with plain SQL Server 2008 I'd suggest a [filestream](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/05/09/sql-server-2008-filestream-part-1.aspx).

According to [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/05/12/ado-net-entity-framework-support-filestream.aspx) this approach will also work for Entity Framework (although the article refers to an older EF version and I haven't tried it personally)

Comment: Thanks--I think I misunderstood the limits. My data is actually only 100K or so, so varbinary(MAX) should work quite well.

Answer (score 2):

`varbinary(max)` is replacement of `Image` type. The storage size of `varbinary(max)` is 2^31 - 1 Bytes => 2GB. it should be enough. `Image` type is deprecated and will be probably removed in future version of SQL server. Use `Binary` type for your data and set its length to `Max`.

Btw. working with such amount of data in EF can be quite bad idea.

Comment: Thanks--I didn't know EF had a problem with BLOB data. Could you point me to a blog post or article, so that I can learn more about it? +1 for the tip.

Comment: @David: I was affraid that you want to work with large blobs. 100K should be OK but you should still work very carefully with projections in queries or table splitting so that blob is loaded only when it is really needed.